# Wordpress error when using get results

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

following up my question in:
[What is the correct and most efficient approach for data ranking ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564712/what-is-the-correct-and-most-efficient-approach-for-data-ranking-ordering)

I am now using the following query to get a ranking back based on a score saved in meta data:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("
    SET @rownum := 0;
    SELECT @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rank, meta_value AS score, post_id
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'my_score'
    ORDER BY meta_value DESC
    ");
```

Now this throws the error "WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax;", as it doesn't like the "SET @rownum :=0;" statement somehow. Removing it makes the query properly work, but as rownum is not set to 0, the ranks are null.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You cannot run multiple query statements in a single query call. This is a restriction of the underlying mysql driver. You'll have to `->get_resultS('set...')` and `->get_results('select ...')` seperately.

Comment: Okay I get it now. Somebody posted a comment with a nice link. Somehow the comment got deleted. Would be great if that somebody could post that link again as an answer.